# How to convert json into hash in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I need to convert json into ps hash object. I tried with

`$data = $event | Select-Object -ExpandProperty data -First 1;`

but that gives me just first level. I would like to convert all inner objects and arrays into hash objects as well. How can I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is `ConvertFrom-Json`

If $event contain is your json, then you'd do:

`$data = $event | ConvertFrom-Json` to get a PSObject from `$event` stored in `$data`

**Complete reproducible example**

```
# Just a random JSON found elsewhere to demonstrate the cmdlet used afterward.
$JsonExample = @"
{
   "countries":[
      {
         "name":"USA",
         "grandfathers":[
            {
               "gFName":"Steve",
               "grandfathersKid":[
                  {
                     "gFKName":"Linda",
                     "kid":[
                        {
                           "name":"Steve JR",
                           "friends":[
                              {
                                 "name":"Kriss|John|Martin|Steven"
                              }
                           ]
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
"@

# Convert Json input into PSObject
$MyObject = $JsonExample | ConvertFrom-Json

# Will returns the list of grandfathers from the first (and only in this case) country.
$MyObject.countries[0].grandfathers
```